# Exporting JTable to csv FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, csv, jtable, export-to-csv

I've got an issue where I'm using the code found here
https://sites.google.com/site/teachmemrxymon/java/export-records-from-jtable-to-ms-excel

However when running the code it throws up the exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/david\test.csv (Permission denied)

Straight away I can see that there's an issue as it looks to use Windows formatting of file paths rather than Linux.

Is there a way I can change this?

The code I have is as follows:

```
private void saveBike1LapActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    JFileChooser bike1FileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int option = bike1FileChooser.showSaveDialog(TrackerWindow.this);
    if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        String filename = bike1FileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName(); 
        String path = bike1FileChooser.getSelectedFile().getParentFile().getPath();
        int len = filename.length();
        String ext = "";
        String file;
        if(len > 4){
    ext = filename.substring(len-4, len);
        }
        if(ext.equals(".csv")){
        file = path + "\\" + filename; 
        }
        else{
        file = path + "\\" + filename + ".csv"; 
        }
        exportBikeLapTimes(bike1LapTimes, new File(file));
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I changed the code to the following:

```
private void saveBike1LapActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    JFileChooser bike1FileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int option = bike1FileChooser.showSaveDialog(TrackerWindow.this);
    if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        String filename = bike1FileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName(); 
        String path = bike1FileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        int len = filename.length();
        String ext = "";
        String file;
        if(len > 4){
    ext = filename.substring(len-4, len);
        }
        if(ext.equals(".csv")){
        file = path; 
        }
        else{
        file = path + ".csv"; 
        }
        exportBikeLapTimes(bike1LapTimes, new File(file));
    }
}
```